# RGB palette designated for ordered values

Tags: c, math, graphics, colors, rgb

I have a function f(x,y), mostly monotonic, which produces some values in the range {0.0 .. 100.0}. I would like to draw them using different colors as a 2D picture, where (x,y) are coordinates and where distinctive colors stand for distinctive values of the function. The problem is following: I don't know how to map the values of this function to RGB color space preserving the order (visibly). I have found that smth. like:

```
R = f(x,y) * 10.0f;
G = f(x,y) * 20.0f;
B = f(x,y) * 30.0f;
color = B<<16|G<<8|R; //@low-endian
```

works fine, but the resulting picture is too dark. If I increase these constants, it makes things not better, because at some moment a color component will be greater than 0xFF, so it will overflow (one color component should be in the range {0 .. 0xFF}.

Do you have any idea how to map values from {0.0 .. 100.0} to 
RGB=[{0 .. 0xFF}<<16|{0 .. 0xFF}<<8|{0 .. 0xFF}] so that the resulting RGB values are visibly Ok?

PS: maybe you know, where to find more info about related theory online? I remember only Comp.Graphics by Foley/Van Dam, but I don't have this book.

UPDATE: I am looking for how to generate a chroma palette like one on the right:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just try clamping the values to a maximum of 255 (0xff).

```
R = min((int)(f(x,y) * 10.0f), 0xff);
G = min((int)(f(x,y) * 20.0f), 0xff);
B = min((int)(f(x,y) * 30.0f), 0xff);
```

**Edit:** There are a lot of different ways to convert to colors automatically, but you might find that none of them generates the exact progression you're looking for. Since you already have a picture of an acceptable palette, one method would be to create a lookup table of 256 colors.

```
#define RGB(R,G,B) (B<<16|G<<8|R)

int palette[256] = { RGB(0,0,0), RGB(0,0,128), ... };

int greyscale = (int)(f(x,y) * 2.559999);
assert(greyscale >= 0 && greyscale <= 255);
int rgb = palette[greyscale];
```

If the lookup table is too much trouble, you could also break the greyscale range into different subranges and do a linear interpolation between the endpoints of each range.

```
int interpolate(int from, int to, double ratio)
{
    return from + (int)((to - from) * ratio); 
}
if (greyscale <= 48)
{
    R = 0;
    G = 0;
    B = interpolate(0, 255, greyscale/48.0);
}
else if (greyscale <= 96)
{
    R = 0;
    G = interpolate(0, 255, (greyscale-48)/48.0);
    B = interpolate(255, 0, (greyscale-48)/48.0);
}
else if ...
```

Comment: I tried already, it doesn't look pretty. For example, it doesn't show pure red color if blue-or/and-green are set to 0xFF

Comment: To be fair, you weren't really clear what you were looking for at first - I thought a progression from black to dark red to yellow to white would be OK. Adding a sample palette to the question helps a lot.

Comment: Thx, it is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you could use the [YUV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV) color model since it is kind of based on two coordinates, i.e. U and V.

This seems more appropriate for the task.

And YUV -> RGB conversion is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert RGB to HSL and increase the brightness/contrast. You can find forumlas for the conversions and other useful info on this page: http://lodev.org/cgtutor/color.html

Answer (score 0):

Use a different colour-space that means you can easily assign coordinates to different colours.

YUV or YCrCb might suit as the UV or CrCb dimensions could be treated as "at right-angles"

Or HSL/HSV if one of your dimensions wraps around like the hue does.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want a heatmap based on the ordered values. Then you have different types of heatmaps. Solution here: http://www.andrewnoske.com/wiki/Code_-_heatmaps_and_color_gradients